# Rails - validate field if another field isn't empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have simple `ApplicationRecord` class like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :surname, presence: true
end
```

Now I'd like to modify my code so that fields must be present only if one of them is present. So, I'll need to have something like:

```
if name_is_present? || surname_is_present?
  validate_name
  validate_surname
else
  #don't validate anything
end
```

I use standard Rails forms, so in case of invalid form I'd like to show my custom validation message associated with concrete field, like it works at standard validations. How can I do this?

Comment: You can create a `ActiveModel::Validator` that validates the presence of both or the absence of both.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla thats actually a much better idea than shoving a bunch of logic into the `if:` and `unless:` options for the normal presence validation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own validations in Rails either by creating a custom validation method in your model or by creating a validator class.

What a validator does is really simple - you run a predicate on the model and if its not met you add an error message to the errors object on the model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :name_or_surname

  private
  def name_or_surname
    if name.present? || surname.present?
      errors.add(:name, "must be present") unless name.present?
      errors.add(:surname, "must be present") unless surname.present?
    end
  end
end
```

Or as a validator class:

```
class NameValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    name, surname = record.name, record.surname
    if name.present? || surname.present?
      errors.add(:name, "must be present") unless name.present?
      errors.add(:surname, "must be present") unless surname.present?
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with NameValidator
end
```

On a side note - use *forename* instead of *name* - its the companion term to surname and is not ambiguous.

Comment: The difference between the two is that the later is reusable and can be tested separately.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :surname, presence: true, unless: :name_blank?

  def name_blank?
    name.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: Does not meet the requirement. "surname should be present only if name is present too and vice versa."

Comment: @max - I realised that this my sentence was little ambiguous. However, adding a second `surname_blank` method to this answer I can reach the same.